# populating dictionary throws NullReferenceEexception

Tags: c#

I have a class with a string and dictionary properties:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> LevelGpa { get; set; }
}
```

Which I am trying to populate into a list of Students:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
{
    {new Student{StudentId = 1, LevelGpa = {{"Freshmen",3.1m}}}},
    {new Student{StudentId = 1, LevelGpa = {{"Sophomore",3.2m}}}},
    ...
};
```

But it is throwing a NullReferenceException at run time -

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Remove the semicolon from the end of `new List<Student>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an instance of LevelGpa inside each instance of Student object:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
{
    {new Student() {
                    StudentId = 1, 
                    LevelGpa = new Dictionary<string, decimal>() {"Freshmen",3.1m} 
                   }
    },

    ...
};
```